# Chrome Extension - Open popup and change the src of default extension Icon by clicking

Tags: popup, icons, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Extension Icons.png

[image: 2]

I understand how to change the src of Icon when clicked:

```
chrome.action.setIcon({path:"icon.png"});
```

For my extension, I want to change the default_icon of the extension to one of the icons I am displaying from my default_popup which can be seen in `extension icon.png`.

How would I make it so the default_icon can change when clicking on one of the icons in my popup.html?

Manifest JS

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "icons": { "128": "./assets/images/logo128.png" },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "./assets/images/logo16.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["popup.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"]
}
```

Index.html

```
<fieldset id="settingsDialog">
        <legend id="settingsLegend" title="Settings">
          Settings
        </legend>
        <h3 id="social-media-blocker-settings-header">Choose Social Blocks Settings options.</h3>
        <h4 class="theme-settings">Appearance</h4>
        <input id="dark-mode" class="toggle" type="checkbox">   
        <label for="dark-mode"></label>
        <h4 class="extension-settings">Extension Icon</h4>
        <img class="filter-bg" src="../../assets/images/extension-icon/icon.png"/>
        <img class="filter-bg" src="../../assets/images/extension-icon/icon-2.png"/>
        <img class="filter-bg" src="../../assets/images/extension-icon/icon-3.png"/>
        <img class="filter-bg" src="../../assets/images/extension-icon/icon-4.png"/>
      </fieldset>
```

Comment: You already know it. The only difference is that in MV3 it's action not browserAction: `chrome.action.setIcon`